# How will I run C# application on server from a code in Custom Object

Tags: c#, archer, rsa-archer-grc

I tried adding this in the custom object.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\archer\mycsharpapp.exe")
```

This gives me error System not defined.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rsa-archer-grc`, but it's possible the the environment your code runs it does not have a reference to `mscorlib` (which has many key components of the `System` namespace) and it instead has its own implementation of the BCL under a different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that it will not be possible for you to write any high-level language statements in a custom object.
Custom objects only support client-side scripting languages like HTML/CSS javascript/jQuery etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there anyway I can start a console Application on click of a button. I know in 5.5. SP4 REST API allows start of a Datafeed. I want to start my application. Thank you again.

Comment: Since starting an application would require a high-level language syntax, it will not be able possible to trigger from a custom object.

Answer (score 1):

Tanveer is correct - you can't directly invoke the application on the server from the JavaScript code embedded into the Archer custom object field.

But you can create a basic web-application (on ASP, .NET, PHP, Java - any language you know) and make it listen to the requests on the given URL with certain properties. As soon as request is received, your web-server can execute the code you need. On top of that you can implement basic security by accepting end user session ID from Archer, so you can validate that given user is indeed logged in to Archer for each request.

Good luck!